# Android TreeView (ListView) Horizontal and Vertical Scrolling with ScrollBar

Tags: android, android-listview, treeview, scroll, scrollbar

I have using [tree-view-list](https://code.google.com/p/tree-view-list-android/) and this implementation have vertical scrollbar. But I want vertical and HORIZONTAL scroll bar. If the row will be bigger then screen size, then user should use horizontal scrolling.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: It internally use List view so its by default behavior is vertical scrolling just add horizontal scroll in each row

Comment: thx for your answer, but it´s not the best solution for me. I try use HorizontalScrollView to each item, but it isn´t good. Is there another way? Do you have any idea?

Comment: try to set Horizontal and Vertical list view in xml I Don't Its Work Or Not...